# How to create TabControl so taht it render different data on each TabItem switching

Tags: .net, silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-5.0, tabcontrol

I want to create a Tabcontrol using MVVM approach where this Tab will have 3 tabitems and each of them will render different things
like one will render  some code in it's tab content and another tabItem will render soem UI element.

What i have in mind is :

Make a mainView.xaml which will have TabControl declared like this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="CENTER.MainTabControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <controls:TabControl Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And make a Viewmodel class for each Tabitem like XmlRenderViewModel.cs (for xml rendering) and UIeLementRenderViewmodel.cs(for UI element rendering)
(please correct me if i am wrong). and will need to make a List of UserControl (3 Usercontrol in this case).

But how to implement that using MVVM approach and xaml ?

Could some one please explain .Thanks a lot I am stuck here since a long time .

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you want each tab item to have it's own data context. This is how you can have a separate view model for each tab. There are many different approaches to set an items data context. Here is a simplistic example on how you could do this.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <sdk:TabControl Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" >
        <sdk:TabItem x:Name="TabItem1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelText}"></TextBlock>
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem x:Name="TabItem2">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelText}"></TextBlock>
        </sdk:TabItem>
    </sdk:TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Then in MainView.xaml.cs, you could have this...

```
public partial class mainView : UserControl
{
    public mainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TabItem1.DataContext = new TabItemOneViewModel();
        TabItem2.DataContext = new TabItemTwoViewModel();
    }
}

public class TabItemOneViewModel
{
    public string ViewModelText { get; set; }

    public TabItemOneViewModel()
    {
        ViewModelText = "Item one text";
    }
}

public class TabItemTwoViewModel
{
    public string ViewModelText { get; set; }

    public TabItemTwoViewModel()
    {
        ViewModelText = "Item two text";
    }
}
```

Comment: .Thanks for the answer but i do not know why your code just displays "Item two text" in both the tabItem.

Comment: I mean whichever written first below IntializeComponent repeats for both TabItem. But why ? and how to do solution ?

Comment: In my question meant something like this : <TabControl>
        <tabData:TabItem1 />
        <tabData:TabItem2 />
        <tabData:TabItem3 />
    </TabControl>

Comment: i have just finshed it.If you want you can see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i finished it doing like this :

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">       
        <controls:TabControl Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" >
            <controls:TabItem x:Name="TabItem1" Height="20" Width="100" Header="UI element">
                <tabData:XmlRender x:Name="ucTab1Data" />            
            </controls:TabItem>
            <controls:TabItem x:Name="TabItem2" Height="20" Width="100" Header="xml data">
                <tabData:UIeLementRender x:Name="ucTab2Data" />       
            </controls:TabItem>
        </controls:TabControl>
    </Grid>


<UserControl x:Class="TabControlLastLifeTry.XmlRender"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelText}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="TabControlLastLifeTry.UIeLementRender"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelText}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

 public class xmlRendereViewModel
    {
        private String viewModelText;
        public String ViewModelText
        {
            get { return viewModelText; }
            set { viewModelText = value; }
        }
        public xmlRendereViewModel()
        {
            viewModelText = "here will be xml rendering";
        }
    }
public class uiElementRendererViewModel
    {
        private String viewModelText;
        public String ViewModelText
        {
            get { return viewModelText; }
            set { viewModelText = value; }
        }

        public uiElementRendererViewModel()
        {
            viewModelText = "here will be UI rendering";
        }

    }
```